# external .js not working after using "parcel index.html"

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this site that im trying to make and I just keep running into the same error over and over again. When I double click on my index.html all the code below works fine but if I use "parcel index.html" in the console it says "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined".
The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Learn Ambivalendrish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/index.scss">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 onclick="test()">This is a header for testing purpose</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and my js is:

```
function test(){
    alert('test alert')
}
```

I already tried doing

```
export function test(){
        alert('test alert')
    }
```

and

```
let test = () =>{
        alert('test alert')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Module bundlers expect a script to be an entry point to the program.

Your problem is that you want the script to create a global variable and then read that global externally.

The bundler doesn't expect that so when it rewrites your script it doesn't take care to ensure that it creates a global variable with that name.

---

Rewrite your code so the script is the entry point.

Don't use intrinsic event attributes, bind the event handlers with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

```
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' () => {
    const heading = document.querySelector('h1');
    heading.addEventListener(test);
});
```

---

Aside: Headings aren't designed to be interactive controls. By default: They don't react to the mouse passing over them. They don't look like things you can click on. Screen readers don't announce them as being interactive. You can't tab to them. If you want something to click on to trigger JS with, use a `<button>`.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, since Im a noob at js I didnt even know there was that addEventListener

Comment: I just used the header as a test object I know that it shouldnt be used as something to click on, just remaking my project and thought I would try and fix that error that I had for a while now.